# Facebook Account-Kit + React.js + Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, facebook, reactjs, spring-boot

I'm starting a new project with Spring boot as backend and React.js as frontent.
Right now I'm struggling with Login/Authentication issue. I would like to provide Account-Kit from facebook but have few queries.
One of them is from where should I create a request to FB sdk for access token? Should it be server (spring), or react which then posts that data to server? Is it possible to call Accout-Kit from java?

I'm quite new to the topic and would be grateful for any answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call AccountKit from your client side js. For additional security, you can use code flow (instead of token flow) and pass the code to your server side. From there you can make a REST call to the Graph API and exchange that code + app secret for a token from server side. There is [an example on the documentation that shows this flow using node.js](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/webjs#examplenodejs), you should be able to make some server side changes to make it run on your setup.

Also, have you tried using [react-account-kit-web](https://github.com/floodfx/react-account-kit-web)?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answer :)
That would mean the flow will look like this:
1. Client app calls Account kit for auth code
2. Client app calls server with auth code
3. Server calls Account Kit with auth code and receives user access token which is stored on server side db
4. server returns ok, access token and Uid back to client. 

This Uid and access token should be also stored on react app side for further server api calls, right? Where specifically? In cookies or in some react redux store?

Comment: Well, it depends on the type of security you want. If you use the code flow then you should not be sending the token back to the client. The whole idea behind the code flow is to keep the client side an arm's length away from having access to the account. This is a security measure mostly aimed towards www clients as it's a lot easier for js and web plugins to be compromised by attackers.

But if you trust the app and want to store the token there directly, the state is a good place to keep it. Cookies are obviously less secure for storing access tokens and not recommended

Comment: Cool, i'm not going to risk with keeping access token in the browser. 
Thank you for the answer!

Comment: Hi, @PouyaLarjani. Could you please tell me if not sending the access token back to the client, the client should send the auth code in every server call? That means the server will "make a REST call to the Graph API and exchange that code + app secret for a token from server side" for each client request. Or should I keep a map Code->AccestToken or even Code->Uid?